# Why can't I share this video on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

This is what I'm doing:

```
FB.ui({
  method:       "feed",
  link:         "https://link-to-site.ninja",
  source:       "https://url-to-s3-hosted-video.mp4",
  caption:      "Video caption",
  type:         "video",
  description:  "Video desc"
}, function(response){});
```

(Also tried different combinations, with and without picture, in which case what would end up showing was the picture and not the clickable video)

And I'm getting either no preview whatsoever, or just the preview image if I provide one, not an actual clickable previewable video. What am I doing wrong? How do I can I get this right?

Thanks!

Comment: ...and what source would that be exactly? hard to help without all the details.

Comment: Source is an MP4 video that verifiable exists in the URL pointed. Cannot share it because it is tangled in a bundle of user privacy and client non-disclosure agreements, but I can though be 100% sure it exists

Comment: you can share any example mp4 that does not work for you. always make sure that others can reproduce the issue with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to put the source as link and it will work (as of 05/2016) but you cannot make it link to another place that's not the video itself.